# How do I display Active Directory jpegPhoto with ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory, binary

I'm creating a company directory using our existing Active Directory information.  I'm able to pull all the data I need, but I wanted to use Active Directory for the photo as well.

I found this snippet of code on this blog: http://plus10.blogspot.com/2008/02/coldfusion-cfldap-display-images-stored.html

```
    <!--- imageFile.cfm --->

<cfsilent>

<cfldap action="QUERY"
name="ldap"
attributes="jpegPhoto"
start="dc=[yourdc],dc=com"
filter="sAMAccountName=[loginname]"
server="[yourserver]"
username="[username]"
password="[password]">

<cfscript>
     ldapPhoto = toString(ldap.jpegPhoto);
     ldapPhoto = binaryDecode(ldapPhoto,"base64");
</cfscript>

</cfsilent><cfcontent type="image/jpeg" variable="#ldapPhoto#">


<!--- to display the image on a page --->

<img src="imageFile.cfm" width="100" height="125" alt="">
```

I plugged in all my server data and I get the error

> The image "....imagefile.cfm" cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Why isn't the image displaying? and how can I correct the code?

I did a `<cfdump>` on the query and it just shows as "jpegPhoto" not binary data.

I can't post the actual page because it is on an internal network only.

Comment: Nevermind!  I replaced all that code (except the query) with
<cfimage
            required
            action = "writeToBrowser"
            source = "#ldap.jpegPhoto#"
            optional
            format = "jpeg"
            isBase64= "yes">

Comment: Can you can go ahead and post that an "answer" (that is allowed on S.O.). That way it will be more visible to others with the same question. Plus, people can vote on it too.

Answer (score 1):

Note, the poster answered her own question.  The `cfcontent` and `img` tags should be replaced with a `cfimage` tag using the source attribute and action="writeToBrowser"

Answer (score 0):

crediting the author: src: https://plus10.blogspot.com/2008/02/coldfusion-cfldap-display-images-stored.html

```
February 12, 2008
ColdFusion CFLDAP - Display images stored in Microsoft Active Directory
Not too hard once I found out how MS stores the data in the photoJpeg field of Active Directory.
```

```
<!--- imageFile.cfm --->
<cfsilent>
<cfldap action="QUERY"
    name="ldap"
    attributes="jpegPhoto"
    start="dc=[yourdc],dc=com"
    filter="sAMAccountName=[loginname]"
    server="[yourserver]"
    username="[username]"
    password="[password]">
    <cfscript>
        ldapPhoto = toString(ldap.jpegPhoto);
        ldapPhoto = binaryDecode(ldapPhoto,"base64");
    </cfscript>
</cfsilent>
<cfcontent type="image/jpeg" variable="#ldapPhoto#">

<!--- to display the image on a page --->
<img src="imageFile.cfm" width="100" height="125" alt="">
```